# Laravel 6.0 input::value"old(' ')"

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

i am using this code but i am not working old function
i have used both using this `<?php echo old('title');  ?>` AND `{{ old('title') }}` Both are not working

```
 <form action="<?php echo route('post.create') ?>" method="GET">
 @csrf
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo old('title');  ?>"></br>
        <textarea name="contant" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo old('contant'); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... does this `post.create` route redirect back with inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Change to `post`

```html
method="POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GET method use request helper function instead of old.

If you use POST method and stil not working. There are few solutions.

Use `withInput()` to go back with data

```
return back()->withInput()->withErrors('Add atleast one image in the post.');
```

[Stack Overflow Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659717/laravel-old-not-working)

Not sure if you remember but i raised a thread the other day where i was having cache problems with Chrome. That might make sense. I tried Canary and same issue so perhaps it's chrome (if that's what OP is using) Please see this posts.
[Laracasts Ref](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/old-values-not-displaying?page=2)